# Sql Get char position of the field

Tags: mysql, sql

how can i get the position of 'A' alphabet?
Eg fields like 
james,
charles,
anderson

Comment: Looking for mysql [**LOCATE**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate)?

Answer (score 1):

Use like below,

```
INSTR (main_string, sub_string);

SELECT INSTR(Field , 'A') FROM table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT INSTR(Field , 'A') FROM table;
```

**Ex:**

```
table

+------------+---------+
|    Name    |  Col1   |
+------------+---------+
| james      | Value2  |
| charles    |  Value2 |
| anderson   |         |
+------------+---------+

SELECT INSTR(Name , 'a') FROM table;
```

You can get location of charactor "a" for each name.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT charindex('a', columnname) FROM tablename;
```